# My receiving data is correct, but it can't save in the new variable

Tags: c++, arduino-uno, nodemcu

**Why the d value does not equal to the data I got?**

I try to let nodemcu get the NTP time and send it to the Arduino UNO. Arduino receives the data from nodemcu, then arrange them into the char data. It went alright so far.

However, when I set the new char to save the data, the value I printed always show the snark mark.

How could I fix it?

**Here is Arduino UNO code**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial s(5,6);

void setup() {
  // Initialize Serial port
  Serial.begin(9600);
  s.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) continue;
}
int k=0;
void seting(char d){
  if(k==0){
    Serial.print("get = ");
    Serial.println(d);
    Serial.println("set Y");
  }else if(k==1){
    Serial.print("get = ");
    Serial.println(d);
    Serial.println("set M");
  }else if(k==2){
    Serial.print("get = ");
    Serial.println(d);
    Serial.println("set D");
  }else if(k==3){
    Serial.print("get = ");
    Serial.println(d);
    Serial.println("set WD");
  }else if(k==4){
    Serial.print("get = ");
    Serial.println(d);
    Serial.println("set H");
  }else if(k==5){
    Serial.print("get = ");
    Serial.println(d);
    Serial.println("set min");
  }else if(k==6){
    Serial.print("get = ");
    Serial.println(d);
    Serial.println("set sec");
  }else{
    k=0;
  }k++;
}

int i = 0;
char data[4];

void loop() {
  while(s.available()){

    char x = s.read();
    if(isdigit(x)){
      data[i]=x;
      i++;
    }
    else{
      Serial.print("data=");
      Serial.println(data);
      seting(data);

      memset(data,0,sizeof(data));
      i=0;
    }
  }
}
```

**Here is nodemcu code**

```
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial s(D6,D5);

const char *ssid     = "dlink-0C00";
const char *password = "yjjri18598";

const long utcOffsetInSeconds = 28800;//TW+8,8*60*60
char daysOfTheWeek[7][12] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

String formattedDate;
String dayStamp;
String timeStamp;

//Define NTP Client to get time
WiFiUDP ntpUDP;
NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP, "asia.pool.ntp.org", utcOffsetInSeconds);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  s.begin(9600);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while ( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ) {
    delay ( 500 );
    Serial.print ( "." );
  }

  timeClient.begin();
}


void loop() {
  timeClient.update();


  formattedDate = timeClient.getFormattedDate();
  int splitT = formattedDate.indexOf("T");
  dayStamp = formattedDate.substring(0, splitT);
  Serial.print("DATE: ");
  Serial.print(dayStamp);
  s.print(dayStamp);
  s.print("/");
  Serial.print(", ");
  Serial.println(daysOfTheWeek[timeClient.getDay()]);
  s.print(timeClient.getDay());
  s.print("/");
  /*timeStamp = formattedDate.substring(splitT+1, formattedDate.length()-1);
  Serial.print("TIME:");
  Serial.println(timeStamp);*/
  int hour = timeClient.getHours();
  int minute = timeClient.getMinutes();
  int second = timeClient.getSeconds();
  Serial.print("TIME:");
  Serial.print(hour);
  s.print(hour);
  Serial.print(":");
  s.print(":");
  Serial.print(minute);
  s.print(minute);
  Serial.print(":");
  s.print(":");
  Serial.println(second);
  s.print(second);
  //s.write(timeStamp);
  s.write("/");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument passed to your function `seting()` is `char` array pointer of `char  data[4];` which may be why your output is not correct. In Arduino code, try changing:
`void seting(char d){`
to
`void seting(char *d){`
as the data passed to `seting()` is an array:
`char data[4];`

Also modify your `println(d)` to use `k` as index into the input argument `d` to `println(d[k])`. If that fixes it, you may want to adjust the size of the `char data[4]` to `char data[7]` so it can be indexed with `k` which seems to go from `0` to `6` according to the Arduino code posted.